# Classic ASP background process using AJAX or other way?

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, background-process

I am working on **Classic ASP** site. In one form results will be fetched from UPS site for displaying shipping rates, now when fetching the results from **UPS site on first request** it usually takes the minutes time to respond back.

So to improved the user's experience with site, this UPS shipping calculation should be done in background and when the background process get finished the result should be displayed to form.

To solve this, we used **jQuery AJAX** approach, but problem is that user have to stay on same page for minute until UPS responds back, if he navigates to other page XHR request will be aborted.

So can you suggest, for background process which way have to choose in Classic ASP or how to navigate to other page without aborting AJAX request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simply created one ASP page which will pass dummy data to UPS service in Async way and than created the background windows process which will keep calling that ASP page at regular interval.

This way whenever the users will come to site they wont experience the slow response due to first UPS request as our background process already keep the UPS channel open.

Answer (score 1):

For slow back-end processes such as this, it’s nearly always a good idea to employ a server-side sql based queue system.

Specifically, on your server, create a binary / service / script to read a queue table, fetch the data from UPS and write results back to the queue table - maintaining a status ID as you go.

Then, all your site needs to do is insert the request into the queue table and then you can use ajax to keep checking the queue table to see if the data is there yet.

A **VERY** basic example (Hard to say without you giving examples):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ParcelQueue](
    [JobID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RequestTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [ParcelTrackingNumber] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [StatusID] [smallint] NULL,
    [Result_DeliveryDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [JobID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[test] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_test_RequestTime]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [RequestTime]
GO
```

**Potential Status IDs:**

1. Pending
2. UPS Response OK
3. UPS Response Failed

Comment: As you said i need to create "binary / service / script to read a queue table", how this can be done using classic ASP? or do i have to use any other thing for this?

Comment: Assuming your using VB Script as your ASP language? if so, move that VBS into a *.vbs file and action it to run using windows task scheduling (that's the quickest way of doing it – you’d just need to tweak the vbs to read the queue table instead of querystring/form data). As for the best way of doing it, that would be a simple windows service – perhaps written in vb.net that will run in the background on the server. (only takes about 10 minutes to knock up a .net windows service).

Comment: But i have to calculate the Shipping cost for particular order, so need to call the Shipping calculation only when checkout.asp page being displayed. So i think it can not be a windows task. But yes it can be Webservice. Correct? Because i don't think windows service will help me, as i need to get shipment for each order when user add items to cart and checkout.

Comment: Also is there any way in classic asp, where the UPS call can be made in background and user can navigate to other pages on site? As i said i had thought of AJAX but navigating to other page will abort the request. Also, windows service and task scheduling wont help as i need data for each order (user will select the items and checkout). So, how to pass request to UPS without stopping user from navigating the site's other pages? Is it possible in classic ASP?

Comment: Your obviously not understanding what i am attempting to say - try giving more information in your question and example code that your using to talk to UPS / what parameters from the users basket are required and we can give you a more useful answer. (A webservice wont help you really as that would be subject to the same problem of pages navigating away mid load, a background call to UPS IS what i was recommending with the code required running as a windows service. Any parameters needed to make that background call would need to be in the queue table).